# AngularJS: change color of a cell based on a condition ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, colors, ng-grid

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPYJ1tGmnarEjf3io1d6?p=preview) code. I want to change the color of the `age` cell for all the rows that their `alert` property is true. I am not sure how to do it. I don't have a separate column for the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go. Refer this modified [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVm9Y13T53su3BfQ37Hn?p=preview). Escaping single quote here but indenting the template for better readability.

```
<div class="ngCellText" 
     ng-class="{\'green\': row.getProperty(\'alert\') == \'true\' }">
         {{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}
</div>
```

Above case is when alert is the string representation of booleans ("true"/"false"). When `alert` is boolean, then the template becomes less clumsy:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="{\'green\': row.getProperty(\'alert\') }">
         {{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
To reduce some verbosity going around there, we can directly use `row.entity.alert`:

```
<div class="ngCellText" 
     ng-class="{\'green\': row.entity.alert == \'true\' }">
         {{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, alert should be a boolean instead of a sring, plus in both cases for improved readability (no escaped single quotes), you can use `row.entity.alert` instead of `row.getProperty(\'alert\')`

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro why we \'green\' and not green?

Comment: Because when we use the above html as template `cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="{\'green\' : row.getProperty(\'alert\') == \'true\' }">{{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}</div>'` the quote has to be escaped. You can altogether remove the quote, but it is a good practice to have classes defined in quotes inside ng-class.

Comment: punker link doesn't seem to be working correctly.  All I'm getting is an empty box from ".gridStyle"

Comment: @16num On a quick overlook it looks like `http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js` is no more a valid resource. Can you try any of the libs from CDN `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ng-grid`. I can play around with it when feasible.