# Dynamically changing cell css based on cell contents in ng-grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

Alright, I have progressed, now I'm just looking to set the css differently if conditions are met.  But I can not figure out correct syntax for the conditionals.

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-style="\'colorChange\' : {{row.getProperty(col.field)}} == {{myFlavor.flavor}}"   ><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'},
```

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':'

Although I believe that syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example on how to dynamically change cell CSS based on cell contents in ng-grid.

```
<div class="ngCellText" 
     ng-class="{\'colorChange\': row.entity.flavor == \'true\' }">
         {{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}
</div>
```

full stackoverflow answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852547/1745230

Comment: Hey Alex,  I have seen that stackflow answer, in my case though, I am attempting to change it on the fly, with user input.  I can get there, but I can't make the grid refresh once the user selects a new argument.